# Java 8 Stream add new object to list from return value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to save the return value of a method and use it to create a new object with which ill add to a list. Here is the block of code for more clarity:

```
final List<FooBoo> fooboos = new ArrayList<>();
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    Optional<Boo> boo = generateBoo(foo);
    if (boo.isPresent()) {
        fooboos.add(new FooBoo(foo, boo.get()));
    }
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
fooboos = foos
            .stream()
            .map(f -> generateBoo(f))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But obviously I'm missing something here which is actuallying creating the `FooBoo` object. How exactly do I do that with the java stream method?

Comment: Do you really want a list, or do you want a `Map<Foo,Boo>`? If it's the latter, consider using [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to populate the map on-the-fly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fooboos = foos
        .stream()
        .map(foo -> generateBoo(foo).map(boo -> new FooBoo(foo, boo))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why not move the `.map` to after the `map(Optional:get)`?

Comment: Because you need the `foo`.

Comment: @Louis - `generateBoo()` returns an `Optional`, and `.map(...)` will, if the optional has a value, apply the map, returning a new `Optional`.  The `.filter` and `.map` then unwraps the `FooBoo`, if present.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible answer is:

```
fooboos = foos.stream()
              .flatMap(foo -> generateBoo(foo)
                                  .map(boo -> new FooBoo(foo, boo))
                                  .map(Stream::of)
                                  .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
              ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think in Java 9 we will see a `stream` method added to `Optional`. Then we will be able to do:

```
fooboos = foos.stream()
              .flatMap(foo -> generateBoo(foo).map(boo -> new FooBoo(foo, boo)).stream())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Which could also be written .flatMap(foo -> generateBoo(foo).map(boo -> Stream.of(new FooBoo(foo, boo)).orElseGet(Stream::empty)

Comment: @JBNizet Good point. That's better. Streams are great, but this stuff is so much harder to write than a `for` loop.

Comment: `optional.stream()` will be equivalent to `optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)`…

Comment: @Holger I'm so tired I can hardly think. Is my Java 9 code is wrong?

Comment: @PaulBoddington I had a hard time making my brain, conditioned by 15+ years of imperative programming, think using functional idioms, but it's coming. You'll probably get used to it.

Comment: Your code is fine. My comment is just a hint about how the Java 8 equivalent can look like (close to JB Nizet’s variant).

Comment: @Holger. I see. Thanks. I'll edit the Java 8 version.

Comment: To make it ready for Java 9, you could add an additional map: `.flatMap(foo -> generateBoo(foo).map(boo -> new FooBoo(foo, boo)).map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))`

Comment: @JBNizet and Holger. I've made the changes. Thanks - it's much better now. I made it a community wiki as it's a collaborative effort already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold on too the `Foo`, but you lose it when you map it to the result of `generateBoo`.  If you have some kind of `Pair` or `Tuple` so that you can map both the `Foo` and the `Boo` into one object, you can then later combine them.  I've seen some people use an array of two objects and `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` as a quick and dirty `Pair` equivalent, both of which are awkward. Whether you use something existing or create your own simple `Pair` object, without questioning the wisdom of using `Optional` in this case, you might do this:

```
fooboos = foos
        .stream()
        .map(f -> new Pair(f, generateBoo(f))
        .filter(p -> p.getV2().isPresent())
        .map(p -> new Pair(p.getV1(), p.getV2().get())
        .map(p -> new Fooboo(p.getV1(), p.getV2()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This solution requires the creation of a `Pair` class (or using an external library containing one).  In this case, it is unnecessary, since `generateBoo()` returns an optional, and so can be "optionally mapped" directly into a `new FooBoo(foo, boo)` as shown by @JB.  The `Pair` object to temporarily hold `foo` and the optional `boo` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yup. That's why I up voted @JB's answer when I saw it after I finished posting mine. Gave myself a head-slap.